# Netcat extremely slow when run through node inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, netcat

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Latest Docker for Mac: Version 17.12.0-ce-mac55 (23011)
2. *docker run -it node /bin/bash*

(Inside the container)

3. *apt-get update*
4. *apt-get install -y netcat*
5. *node*
6. Run the following:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

console.time("Executed nc in ");
var output = child_process.spawnSync('nc', ['-w', '5', '<hostname of host with SSH>', 22, '<<<', '\0']).stdout.toString();
console.timeEnd("Executed nc in ");
console.log(output);
```

The result will contain *Executed nc in : XX ms*, I am seeing XX in the 10 second range.

When I run netcat on the same container outside of node with ***nc -w 5 [hostname with SSH] 22 <<< '\0'***, it executes in less than a second.

Comment: 10 seconds sounds like a DNS resolution issue. Maybe you are not using a fully qualified domain name so the container is using search domains to find the real one? Maybe the SSH server has `UseDNS` turned on?

Comment: what Matt he said

Comment: @Matt the interesting part is when I exit out of node and run nc on the container, it takes < 1s (mentioned in my post)

Comment: Docker does add a DNS server between the container and host. Add the `dnsutils` package to the container and see if `dig sshhost` works immediately.

Comment: @Matt Yes, adding dig to the conainer with 'apt-get install -y dnsutils' and running var output = child_process.spawnSync('dig', ['+trace','<hostname of host with SSH>']).stdout.toString(); through node runs within 1 second.

Comment: I will be using socat instead of nc as it achieves the same result I'm looking for (checking to see if SSH daemon is running) and is not prone to the slowness.